# Sorting and floating dynamic html elements based on their publish date

Tags: php, wordpress, css, css-float

I can't seem to think of a logical solution to this.

I work a website (based on Wordpress) that renders "posts" based on their publish date onto a view. And I want the latest post published to be the first visible post on my page – and this is of course the usual and normal way Wordpress handles posts. So the latest post is on top.

However I have a layout solution where my posts are squared containers and they are floated right. This means the latest post is floated to the top right corner of the page … but I'd like it to be on the top left position of the floated elements.

Here is a visualization:

[image]

So this is my current case … I want the containers to be floated right (they have different widths). However the position of each container should be different.

The thing I want is this …

[image]

Any idea on how to that? But remember the layout should be floated right.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: add orderby=DESC on the wp_query

Comment: I can't figure out why you would want it floated right when you want it to behave as if it floated left, what you could do is make a container around you posts and make that floated right and inside floated left, perhaps that would solve it?

Comment: That's going to be quite tricky even _with_ JavaScript. You'll need to figure out how many posts can fit in each row, then add them in reverse order.

Comment: @Fábio that wouldn't do the job. in that case the latest item would be in the bottom right corner of the page instead of top left.

Comment: You can make 2 wp_queries, and in the second one make it ignore first 3 posts. plus, orderby=desc on both ones

Comment: that's the simplest you can do, in my opinion. It works as intended, you just have to code it... I could help you if you add me on messenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work even if the items (posts) have different widths: http://jsfiddle.net/PvGHu/1/

Comment: No, at least not without some changes. The current implementation changes the order that the posts are listed in the DOM so that it no longer matches the original sort-by-date ordering. If you simply run it again, you'll get the wrong result. You would need to preserve the original order somehow, e.g. by keeping the `items` array around until you need it again, or by storing the post timestamp in a hidden `<span>` (or something) and re-sorting the post list before you run the function again. Edit: This was a response to a comment that appears to have been deleted.

Comment: Hey Janis, thank you! One last question, how much simpler would the code be if the width's of the posts are always 300px? So each item is exactly 300px in width. But the heights are different … http://jsfiddle.net/PvGHu/2/ I would need to have a cleafix after every third element. Because my layout is 900px in width and each item is 300px in width so exactly three items fit into one row.

Comment: It would be much simpler. Probably 1/3rd of what it is now. With different post widths, the main difficulty is figuring out how many posts fit on each row. If they're all the same width, you can just calculate that once and process all posts in one go.

Comment: And different heights like I updated in the example. I have no idea how to add a clear after every third item. Would you mind helping me out here again.